# Can we call a C function inside a log rotation process on ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, logging, logfile, logrotate

I need to call only a date expiry C function inside a log rotation process on daily basis. Can we do that? I am new to job rotation and cron job scheduling.

Comment: Cronjobs don't call functions. They call programs. It doesn't matter what language they were written in.

Comment: @Gerhardh So can I call a function inside a log file rotation process. My requirement is to call a particular function which monitors the expiry of a file on daily basis. Can I do that by a log file rotation process in ubuntu ??

Comment: I am not that familiar with logrotation. Why do you even want to have a function called and not a program? Normally you compile your functions into a binary and have it executed by cronjob. Which makes your problem independend from the languages and is more suitable for SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.